# Group by status ID but have a min and max date

Tags: sql-server

I have a number of rows which are ordered by seq column which is the sequence they are in.  You could also order by date1 but there can be more than one row with the same date so the seq column is used.  I would like to select the status and the period the status covers.  If the status in row 1 is the same as the status in row 2 then I want to show 1 row in my results with the date1 of row 1 and date2 of row 2.  Of course there could be many rows of the same status in reality and I have simulated a few.  My second table shows the results I would like from selecting data from the first.

select statusid, min(date1), max(date2) from table
Group by statusid

as you will know will group all the statuses together and my 2nd table would only have 4 rows, but I can’t order it to get the 5th row to be a repeat with a different date period because I can’t use the seq column as it’s not in the results.  If it was it would of course it would not create the results I want.  Is there a way I can get the results shown in the 2nd table?  Thanks for you help.

| seq | eventid | statusid | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 24/3 | 25/3 |
| 2 | 8 | 1 | 25/3 | 28/3 |
| 3 | 13 | 2 | 28/3 | 03/4 |
| 4 | 15 | 3 | 03/4 | 20/4 |
| 5 | 17 | 3 | 20/4 | 01/5 |
| 6 | 21 | 5 | 01/5 | 13/5 |
| 7 | 32 | 5 | 13/5 | 24/5 |
| 8 | 41 | 2 | 24/5 | 27/6 |

| statusid | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24/3 | 28/3 |
| 2 | 28/3 | 03/4 |
| 3 | 03/4 | 01/5 |
| 5 | 01/5 | 24/5 |
| 2 | 24/5 | 27/6 |

Apologies as I’m writing on my phone and the formatting is difficult for my fat fingers, just wanted to get the question out tonight.

Comment: This is a typical gaps and islands type of query. It has been asked and answered dozens and dozens of times.

Comment: I will look for that term.  I have never heard of that before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical gaps/ islands problem, you need to group your `statusid` values into their respective islands.

Several possible approaches can be taken, my preference is to use `lag` to identify when the value changes, then a running total of this flag can be used to add a sequential value from which to group by:

```
with grp as (
  select *, Sum(idgrp) over(order by seq) grp
  from (
    select *,
      case when 
        statusid != Lag(statusid) over(order by seq) then 1 
      else 0 end idgrp
    from t
  )t
)
select statusid, Min(date1) date1, Max(date2) date2
from grp
group by statusid, grp
order by grp;
```

Example [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AFuuAvBz)

Comment: Thank you that was perfect Stu..